# Debug/Solve Gradle's "Out of memory. Java heap space" error

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am refactoring a Legacy-Gradle project upgrading from 5.6.4 to 7.5.1. I did not include all projects yet, but I am getting the error

```
* What went wrong:
Out of memory. Java heap space

Possible solution:
 - Check the JVM memory arguments defined for the gradle process in:
   gradle.properties in project root directory
```

I don't know where this error comes from, but I suspect 3 things:

1. something changed between Gradle-versions
2. something is different between IntelliJ (current used IDE) and Eclipse (previously used IDE)
3. I messed up the project's Gradle structure

Any hint what I can do to find out what's going on? Is there another solution than giving more space in gradle.properties (I have already `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g` and giving more feels like wrong in terms of scaling)? It seems like more tasks are running simoultaniously than before.

Comment: You should be able to verify the three suspected things yourself  by making only one change at a time.

Comment: I did run the project in Eclipse and I still get the error (if I did everything right). Therefore I do not think it's 2). But 1) and 3) are coupled to each other, so I can not test them separated...

Comment: When and where do you get this error? have you tried running(building?) from the command line by Gradle?

Comment: CLI, Eclipse, IntelliJ... I am still testing, but it seems like there was a bug with checkstyle (https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/10934). I used version 9.2.1. After upgrading to 9.3 it seems like the error is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there was a bug with the checkstyle plugin (github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/10934). I switching from 9.2.1 to 9.3 and the error was gone.